# Hide or change mouse pointer in Linux/X11 when pointer is actively grabbed by others

Tags: c++, c, linux, mouse, x11

I failed to hide or change mouse pointer when mouse pointer is actively grabbed by some other client.

I have tried XChangeActivePointerGrab and XDefineCursor.
Main question is: During XDnD (Drag and Drop), when the mouse pointer enters my window, I cannot hide it.

I am going to use that in Synergy: When user is dragging something to another display (on some other computer) mouse pointer on the first one should be hidden.

Comment: See < http://www.tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html > - "If a cursor is specified, it is displayed regardless of what window the pointer is in..." And when one client has the cursor grabbed no other client can grab it away (see < http://www.tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/pointer-grabbing.html >).  I suspect the best solution will be something that doesn't look quite right but is "good enough".  If you could describe how you plan to implement this a in a bit more detail (on a blog perhaps?) I or someone else might have some ideas.

Comment: Follow-up to my last comment: how about displaying a visible window on the system the drag is originating from representing the target desktop of the system the Synergy cursor is currently in, and move the mouse cursor on the originating system within that window to match its position on the target?  If feasible you could even display some representation of the target desktop inside the window.